# Memory leak in AVMutableComposition

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, avfoundation

I'm a little confused as to why every occurrence of this line is seen as a memory leak:

```
let asset = AVMutableComposition()
```

Looked on SO and didn't really find any answers. Just want to clear up some of the memory leaks before I submit to app store and this one is bothering me bad

Comment: “seen as a memory leaK” seen by whom?

Comment: debug memory graph in xcode

Comment: Don’t believe that.  Run on device and use Instruments.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same.  Instruments shows that every AVMutableComposition leaks in xpc low level logic.  Just this statement causes 6 leaks.

```
AVMutableComposition * composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
composition = nil;
```